# Position the anchor point in the exact center of the smaller circle

Tags: after-effects

What is the best way to position the anchor point in the exact center of the smaller circle of this PNG figure?

My methods were all manual and in this way I did not have good results.

[image]

Comment: The horizontal centre is easy, just use AE's align tools. For the vertical, have you tried drawing a circle over it with the shape tool and moving it until it lines up? Zoom in a lot and you should get pretty close just by eye.

Comment: I Will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a different file by filling in the desired region in red.

[image]

Go to website: [WOLFRAM DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/)

And enter the code below:

```
image=Import["C:\\Users\\Image.png"]
value={ImageDimensions[image]}-{Mean[ImageValuePositions[image,Red][[All,#]]]&/@{1,2}}
```

[image]

Enter the values offered for the anchor point. In this case: **386.995** and **173.982**

[image]

[image]